# How add a custom control panel in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

Is there an example that shows how to add a custom control panel in OpenLayers 3?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this example. Shows how to build a custom control. 
[custom control](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/custom-controls.html)

And here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/dpe4zggq/) just to demonstrate a custom toolbar

Comment: the sample is just a button and it cannot put a lot controls or panel.
If using Openlayers 2, I can use control.panel. I can implement it by OL 3

Comment: do not expect to get everything up and running. The example just shows the way to do things. Here is a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/dpe4zggq/) I have made to add some extra button and a select list. But you may add as many html stuff you want

Comment: Hi Pavios, thank you very much. I know I should not expect to get everything up and running. This is because client and supervisor want this and It can be implement in google map. This is why I think it should be done. Anyway, Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Pavios, do you know how to do a local map. My client's environment is offline.  I need a direction to study. I have study about Geoserver but it seems only show line, points,road and so on.

Comment: I havent had such requirement in the past, so I am not very familiar. Better add a new question. glad to help

Comment: Hi Pavios, Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help. I implement it by GeoServer.

Comment: Great example.  Apparently there is no default layer selection control in OpenLayers.